# Why does Spinner.getChildAt return null?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I'm using `Spinner` in one of my fragment. When i go to this fragment from backstack (using back button) it gives me a `NullPointerException`.

Here is some code

> Populating spinner:

```
SpinnerData data = new SpinnerData(0, getString(R.string.auTypeLabel));
        mAdapter.add(data);

        data = new SpinnerData(AU_STANDART_TYPE, getString(R.string.auTypeStandart));
        mAdapter.add(data);

        data = new SpinnerData(AU_FIXED_TYPE, getString(R.string.auTypeFixed));
        mAdapter.add(data);

        data = new SpinnerData(AU_REVERSE_TYPE, getString(R.string.auTypeReverse));
        mAdapter.add(data);

        mAuTypeSpinnerLayout.getSpinner().setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

> onActivityCreated section:

mSpinner.getChildAt(0)).getTextSize();

Which gives me the following:

`mSpinner` is not null

`mSpinner.getCount()` is 4

But `mSpinner.getChildAt(0)` is `null`

Maybe I should call `getChildAt` method on another section?

Comment: check this: `mSpinner.getChildCount();`

Comment: How do you populate the spinner?

Comment: @walkmn hmm, `getChildCount()` is 0

Comment: why would you want to that `(mSpinner.getChildAt(0))` ?

Comment: @1615903 i edit a main post

Comment: @pskink i want to know text size of item `((TextView)mSpinner.getChildAt(0)).getTextSize();`

Comment: Apparently the code that populates the spinner doesn't get executed when you return from a different activity. You could try moving that piece of code to your activity's `onResume()`

Answer (score 3):

It because `getChildCount()` is 0 -> `mSpinner.getChildAt(0)` returned null

You may try this:

```
if (mSpinner.getChildCount() > 0) {
   ((TextView) mSpinner.getChildAt(0)).getTextSize();
}
```

Comment: Yes i can, but i didn't know what my size is :(

I think the problem is that `getChildCount` returns only visible elements, and i call this at `onActivityCreated` method, and spinner is invisible now.

Comment: you may do it from your adaper, paste your adaper code